# get values of checked and unchecked in looping form

Tags: php, checkbox, codeigniter-3

i have multiple insert query and i want to filtering if data checked it will inserting to my database, but if not checked data cannot inserted, this my form:

```
$employee = 10;
$att_employee = 5;
<input type="hidden" name="att_employee" value="$att_employee" />
foreach ($employee as $emp){
<input type="text" name="field1[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="field2[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="field2[]" value="1" />
}
```

in my controller

```
$data=array();
for($i=0; $i < $att_employee; $i++) { 
$data[$i] = array(
'field1'=> field1[$i],
'field2'=> field2[$i],
)
}
```

maybe i must create if condition in my controller but before to it i have some problem, my checkbox fields not return values

Comment: I think you missed one quote(") here <input type="checkbox" name="field2[] value="1" /> plus you should use different name for the input

Comment: my question just sample of my real code

Comment: As you using the same name (array) for your hidden input and checkbox the values are appending there, try to use different name for the checkbox

Comment: it return Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($employee as $index => $emp): ?>

<input type="text" name="field1[<?php echo $index; ?>]" />
<input type="hidden" name="field2[<?php echo $index; ?>]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="field3[<?php echo $index; ?>]" value="1" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now you will get employee index id when you will receive the data.

Comment: @rajaarab, You should at-least accept this answer. This is how stackoverflow works.